# Oven baking potatoes to make mashed potato/pomme puree - how to store the cooked skins

Tags: storage-method, potatoes

Whenever I make pomme puree or mashed potatoes (with warm milk/cream and softened butter depending), I always bake the potatoes after covering them in oil & salt and use the inside for mash/pomme puree. However, with most meals (like the lamb roast dinner I am making today), I do not particularly want to eat the potatoes skins there and then.

I tried Googling but most of it just comes up with `how to store potatoes` which is unhelpful. How can I store the cooked skins for the next day (loaded skins with tuna and mayonnaise for example)?

My first thought was just to let them cool and then fridge them before putting them back in the oven prior the next day but I am not sure if this is optimal or if they will go soggy etc.

Comment: I’ve never tried storing them filled, but they do okay empty in the fridge and then you can reheat and fill later

Comment: @Joe thank you, I assumed so but just wanted confirmation before I ruined them by accident! I am happy to accept an answer if you want to provide one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chill the unfilled potato skins, and then reheat them and fill them (or fill and heat, as appropriate for the filling)

I would recommend letting them cool some before packing up, and using waxed paper or similar between layers so they don’t stick together.

It’s possible that they might be a little more firm than freshly baked, so you want them to be more tender, may want to scoop the skins out to slightly thinner than you typically would.  I usually don’t have an issue with this, but I suspect that it would be affected by potato variety.